# How to get referrer value in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I am using NextJS routing, but when I try to use `document.referrer` in my code, it does not return any value. How can I resolve this issue?

I am using the `router.events.on` method to listen for changes in navigation, but I haven't found a way to retrieve the referrer value.

Answer (score 3):

The `headers()` function from NextJS may be helpful. Here's an example from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers):

```jsx
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
 
export default function Page() {
  const headersList = headers()
  const referer = headersList.get('referer')
 
  return <div>Referer: {referer}</div>
}
```